# Bad performance in chrome running this site

Tags: javascript, image, performance, google-chrome, web

This is my first website , it running good in IE but bad at Google Chrome
especially when zoom in and out

http://robovics.com/e-dec_Admin/project.html?id=0&name=Project1

how i can know why?
If there any performance analyzer tool to check the problem

Comment: Anon mask in your profile photo and a link to a unknown website... I wish you luck. You should check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, conveniently enough there are developer tools built into Chrome (as well as every other major browser) that let you profile, debug, or inspect the performance or source code of a webpage. To open the console CTLR+SHIFT+I (Windows) or CMD+OPT+I (Mac). Now you'll see a console at the bottom of the webpage go to the Network tab at the top of it and refresh the page; it will tell you how long its taking Chrome to load the resources for your website. For even more insight check out this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). I hope that helps.